# Excel count how many times a value appears in a range looking within cells

Tags: arrays, excel, search, excel-formula, count

I have a column with unique emails and I need to count how many times each one is in another range with emails BUT in this one the cells can contain more than one email, and they are separated by a blank space, is there a way to count them?

[image: It's something like this]

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following it will give you the exact number of occurrences as per your screenshots:

[image]

---

```
=LET(
     _Instances, SEQUENCE(,MAX(LEN(AllEmailsList[AllEmail])-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(AllEmailsList[AllEmail]," ",))+1)),
     SUM(N(IFNA(TEXTSPLIT(TEXTAFTER(" "&AllEmailsList[AllEmail]," ",_Instances)," "),"")=[@[Unique Email]])))
```

---

Another alternative way using `FIND()` & `COUNT()`

[image]

---

```
=COUNT(FIND(" "&[@[Unique Email]]&" "," "&AllEmailsList[AllEmail]&" "))
```

---

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--ISNUMBER(SEARCH(" "&[@[Unique email]]&" "," "&othertable[allEmail]&" ")))
```

If you know that there will not be situtations where one email address is also part of another email address in your unique list, you could simply use countif:

```
=COUNTIF(othertable[allEmail],"*"&[@[Unique email]]&"*")
```

Comment: I feel so dumb because I tried this but dismissed because the results were wrong according to factual data, but now I realized the unique values columns was incomplete. this works great, thank you.

Comment: Note that if `[AllEmail]` could contain the same address within the same line multiple times it'd count as 1.

Answer (score 0):

You can [convert](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/split-text-into-different-columns-with-the-convert-text-to-columns-wizard-30b14928-5550-41f5-97ca-7a3e9c363ed7) the range with multiple per cell adresses into a range and then use [COUNTIF](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=countif+excel) to count them. Then again, if are you looking for a one step solution you can try this array formula:

```
=SUM((LEN($D$2:$D$11&" ")>LEN(SUBSTITUTE($D$2:$D$11&" ",A2&" ","")))*1)
```

This one is for cell B2. Just remember to use Ctrl+Shift+Enter when you confirm it. To be fair: this past formula will not detect any double occuring address if it's in the same cell (like "email_2 email2"). Since i can't be sure you won't encounter such eventuality, this array formula should count these cases too:

```
=SUM((LEN($D$2:$D$11&" ")-LEN(SUBSTITUTE($D$2:$D$11&" ",A2&" ","")))/LEN(A2&" "))
```